# Setting PHP upload_max_filesize in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, php

I have edited /etc/php.ini and have inserted the following line of code to set the subject variable:

```
 upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

However, within a Joomla website on this host, the PHP Information screen says that this variable is set to only 2M.  I have restarted Apache, then I restarted the machine, etc.  Nothing seems to allow me to change this var.  Installing some Joomla extensions requires this limit to be higher.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: A well-written question. Concise, and with relevant detail (i.e. tells what version of OS X, and references a specific config option in PHP by name. I Added 'code' formatting for easier readability.

Answer (score 2):

Have you modified the post_max_size too ?

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Check "PHP post_max_size overrides upload_max_filesize" here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754133/php-post-max-size-overrides-upload-max-filesize